# Jquery Ui Drag and drop with some ease or gravity

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, gravity

Basically I am designer and not a programmer. I am trying to build some application. You can see my basic code here at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mailverma/WWfTN/1/. 
The idea is, user can sort 6 most descriptive and 6 least descriptive words and will drag and drop them in respective container. 
I need help regarding enhancements in this code.

1)  Issue in this current code is, when I reset, after that, sometimes yellow rectangles are not accepted in some dotted slots. If you place same yellow rectangle in other slot it will be accepted.  I don’t know the reason. Please help.

2)   When user drags and throws yellow rectangle towards green or blue container, it should go by some gravity force. When more than half of yellow rectangle comes inside blue or green container, it should automatically snap to available empty dotted slot. Overlapping is not expected here.

3)  I want to change class of yellow rectangle holder in top (In my code it is li) when yellow rectangle is dropped in blue or green container. So that user can drag back to original position.

Please help me in this code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a physics engine like box2d
http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/
I think you can do amazing things with that